# Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault:11

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, swift3

While compiling my project i keep on getting this error, some time my project runs smoothly but sometimes xcode shows this error.I've also added AddMembersViewController.swift which I think is causing the problem

```
MergeSwiftModule normal x86_64 /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Rendezvous.swiftmodule
    cd /Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -emit-module /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MoreViewController~partial.swiftmodule /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/HomePageViewController~partial.swiftmodule /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RegisterViewController~partial.swiftmodule /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/LocationSelectorViewController~partial.swiftmodule /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AddMembersViewController~partial.swiftmodule /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SetupViewController~partial.swiftmodule /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ViewController~partial.swiftmodule /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate~partial.swiftmodule /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/UpdateViewController~partial.swiftmodule -parse-as-library -target x86_64-apple-ios10.1 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.2.sdk -I /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks -F /Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/FirebaseAuth/Frameworks/frameworks -F /Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks -F /Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/FirebaseDatabase/Frameworks -F /Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks/frameworks -F /Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks -F /Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/GoogleMaps/Base/Frameworks -F /Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/GoogleMaps/Maps/Frameworks -F /Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/GooglePlaces/Frameworks -F /Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks -enable-testing -g -import-objc-header /Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Rendezvous/Rendezvous-Bridging-Header.h -module-cache-path /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -D DEBUG -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/Rendezvous-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/Rendezvous-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/Rendezvous-all-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/Rendezvous-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/Firebase/Core/Sources -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/Headers/Public -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseAnalytics -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseAuth -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseCore -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseDatabase -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseInstanceID -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/Headers/Public/GTMSessionFetcher -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleInterchangeUtilities -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleMaps -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/Headers/Public/GooglePlaces -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleSymbolUtilities -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleToolboxForMac -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -Xcc -working-directory/Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous -emit-module-doc-path /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Rendezvous.swiftdoc -module-name Rendezvous -emit-objc-header-path /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Rendezvous-Swift.h -o /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Rendezvous.swiftmodule

0  swift                    0x000000010fd283ad PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 45
1  swift                    0x000000010fd27b56 SignalHandler(int) + 790
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fffd1db0bba _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff52f3aba8 _sigtramp + 2165874696
4  swift                    0x000000010d334996 swift::ModuleFile::getType(llvm::PointerEmbeddedInt<unsigned int, 31>) + 806
5  swift                    0x000000010d32d178 swift::ModuleFile::getDecl(llvm::PointerEmbeddedInt<unsigned int, 31>, llvm::Optional<swift::DeclContext*>) + 18664
6  swift                    0x000000010d338b2c swift::ModuleFile::maybeReadPattern() + 332
7  swift                    0x000000010d32bd82 swift::ModuleFile::getDecl(llvm::PointerEmbeddedInt<unsigned int, 31>, llvm::Optional<swift::DeclContext*>) + 13554
8  swift                    0x000000010d33d4a7 swift::ModuleFile::loadAllMembers(swift::Decl*, unsigned long long) + 647
9  swift                    0x000000010d6d006a (anonymous namespace)::Traversal::visitNominalTypeDecl(swift::NominalTypeDecl*) + 314
10 swift                    0x000000010d6ce01b (anonymous namespace)::Traversal::doIt(swift::Decl*) + 219
11 swift                    0x000000010d085c2f swift::SILPassManager::SILPassManager(swift::SILModule*, llvm::StringRef) + 1423
12 swift                    0x000000010d08acef swift::runSILDiagnosticPasses(swift::SILModule&) + 159
13 swift                    0x000000010cd34f7e performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 19758
14 swift                    0x000000010cd2e2b3 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 17859
15 swift                    0x000000010ccea5cf main + 8239
16 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fffd1ba3255 start + 1
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -emit-module /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MoreViewController~partial.swiftmodule /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/HomePageViewController~partial.swiftmodule /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RegisterViewController~partial.swiftmodule /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/LocationSelectorViewController~partial.swiftmodule /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AddMembersViewController~partial.swiftmodule /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SetupViewController~partial.swiftmodule /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ViewController~partial.swiftmodule /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate~partial.swiftmodule /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/UpdateViewController~partial.swiftmodule -parse-as-library -target x86_64-apple-ios10.1 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.2.sdk -I /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks -F /Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/FirebaseAuth/Frameworks/frameworks -F /Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks -F /Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/FirebaseDatabase/Frameworks -F /Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks/frameworks -F /Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks -F /Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/GoogleMaps/Base/Frameworks -F /Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/GoogleMaps/Maps/Frameworks -F /Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/GooglePlaces/Frameworks -F /Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks -enable-testing -g -import-objc-header /Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Rendezvous/Rendezvous-Bridging-Header.h -module-cache-path /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -D DEBUG -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/Rendezvous-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/Rendezvous-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/Rendezvous-all-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/Rendezvous-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/Firebase/Core/Sources -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/Headers/Public -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseAnalytics -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseAuth -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseCore -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseDatabase -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseInstanceID -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/Headers/Public/GTMSessionFetcher -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleInterchangeUtilities -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleMaps -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/Headers/Public/GooglePlaces -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleSymbolUtilities -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleToolboxForMac -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -Xcc -working-directory/Users/prakhar/Desktop/iOS/Rendezvous -emit-module-doc-path /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Rendezvous.swiftdoc -module-name Rendezvous -emit-objc-header-path /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Rendezvous-Swift.h -o /Users/prakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rendezvous-ardcsmuqhgsylxapkcrnrtdcwvnu/Build/Intermediates/Rendezvous.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Rendezvous.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Rendezvous.swiftmodule 
1.  While loading members for 'AddMembersViewController' at <invalid loc>
2.  While deserializing decl #143 (PATTERN_BINDING_DECL)
3.  While deserializing decl #13 (VAR_DECL)
```

AddMembersViewController

```
@IBOutlet weak var eventName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var memberName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var addButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var finishButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var createButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeAndDate: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var errorLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var rCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D!
    var members:[String]=[]
    var ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "event-data")
    var refUser = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "user-data")
    var event:String = ""
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "members")
        memberName.isEnabled=false
        addButton.isHidden=true
        finishButton.isHidden=true
        let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
        members.append((user?.displayName!)!)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    @IBAction func cancel(_ sender: Any) {
        let alert=UIAlertController.init(title: "confirmation", message: "Are you sure you want to cancel", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {(action:UIAlertAction!) in
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "home", sender: self)
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "No", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func create(_ sender: Any) {
        eventName.isEnabled = false
        timeAndDate.isEnabled = false
        createButton.isHidden = true
        addButton.isHidden = false
        memberName.isEnabled = true
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        errorLabel.text=""
    }

    @IBAction func add(_ sender: Any) {
        errorLabel.text=""
        let newUser:String = memberName.text!
        for one in members{
            if(one == newUser){
                errorLabel.text="\(newUser) already added"
                return
            }
        }
        var flag=false
        refUser.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
            let value=snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
            for val in (value.allKeys){
                //print(val)
                if(newUser == val as? String){
                    flag=true
                    break
                }
                //print("inside \(flag)")
            }
            if(flag){
                self.members.append(newUser)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.memberName.text=""
                self.finishButton.isHidden=false
            }
            else{
                self.errorLabel.text="No such UserNAme found"
            }
        })

    }
    @IBAction func finish(_ sender: Any) {
        let event=eventName.text!
        if(members.count<2){
            let alert=UIAlertController.init(title: "No members added", message: "Add atleast one more member", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        let formatter=DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd ,YYYY"
        let date = formatter.string(from: timeAndDate.date)
        formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
        let time = formatter.string(from: timeAndDate.date)
        ref.child("\(event)/latitude").setValue(rCoordinate.latitude)
        ref.child("\(event)/longitude").setValue(rCoordinate.longitude)
        ref.child("\(event)/date").setValue(date)
        ref.child("\(event)/time").setValue(time)
        ref.child("\(event)/noOfMembers").setValue(members.count)
        for i in 0..<members.count{
            ref.child("\(event)/member\(i)").setValue(members[i])
            refUser.child("\(members[i])/noOfEvents").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
                var no = snapshot.value as! Int
                no += 1
                self.refUser.child("\(self.members[i])/noOfEvents").setValue(no)
                self.refUser.child("\(self.members[i])/event\(no)").setValue(event)
            })
        }
        let alert=UIAlertController.init(title: "Done", message: "Event created..!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {(action:UIAlertAction) in
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "home", sender: self)
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return members.count
    }


    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "members", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text=members[indexPath.row]
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.displayName
        if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete){
            if(indexPath.row == 0){
                let alert=UIAlertController.init(title: "Error !!", message: "You cannot remove yourself..!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            else{
                members.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                if(members.count < 2){
                    finishButton.isHidden = true
                }
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    public func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
        return 1
    }
```

Comment: Have you changed your code from Xcode 7 to Xcode 8?

Comment: You can try deleting your derived data.

Comment: this happen sometime when complier confuse what happen in your code 
you can try after clean x code

Comment: @koropok didn't work

Answer (score -1):

Command+Shift+K to clean your project, then File->Workspace settings->the little arrow next to DerivedData and delete the folder. That sometimes fixes the issue.

Also, I noticed that in Xcode 8.3 beta this issue is no longer present.

Comment: Another solution that worked for me is force unwrapping the variables that you are sure they contain a value (also the "something.text!")

Comment: there's tons of code, how do i get know which one i have to force unwrap

Comment: First try the something.text! ones

Comment: The log says the error is at AddMembersViewController. Check the code for ambiguities or for variables that do not need to be optional.

Comment: I have added the code in AddMembersViewController to the question. Please can you check and let me know what is causing the problem

Comment: Delete `@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!` , you don't need this, when you type `tableView` you automatically refer to the table view itself, no need for declaration.

Comment: And don't forget to unlink it from storyboard also

Comment: It only works for tableView methods, but not in viewDidLoad(). How do i register my table if i delete UITableView outlet

Comment: No, i have just added UITableView to a ViewController because I am also doing some other operation in it

Comment: Open Terminal and type `sudo gem install cocoapods`. Then navigate to the project folder, comment or remove all pods from the podfile, run `pod install`, then uncomment or add the pods and run `pod install` again.

Comment: Have you run sudo gem install cocoapods again?

Comment: yeah i have re-install cocoapods using sudo gem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Telling people to reset the environment, rather than how they can debug how the compiler segfaulted isn't reusable, or even good, advice. This advice would have been better suited as a comment.